# Orchard CMS ResizeMedia url from Controller.

Tags: orchardcms-1.7

I'm trying to use the

```
@Display.ResizeMediaUrl()
```

In Orchard 1.7.2, However I need to get the value of the resized Media url in a controller so I can return it to a javascript function.

I can see in there is a

```
[shape]
public void ResizeMediaUrl
```

Shape in MediaShapes.cs (Orchard.MediaProcessing.Shapes) but I'm not sure how to use this. from a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a reference to `IImageProfileManager` in your controller which you set up in the Constructor

```
private readonly IImageProfileManager _imageProfileManager;
```

Within the Controller Action you can call `GetImageProfileUrl` which will resize the image for you.

I've hacked this out of the ResizeMediaUrl shape and hardcoded the Mode, Alignment and Colour settings.

e.g.

```
private string DoTheResize(int Width, int Height, string path)
{
    var Mode = "pad";
    var Alignment = "middlecenter";
    var PadColor = "000000";

    var state = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"Width", Width.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},
        {"Height", Height.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},
        {"Mode", Mode},
        {"Alignment", Alignment},
        {"PadColor", PadColor},
    };

    var filter = new FilterRecord
    {
        Category = "Transform",
        Type = "Resize",
        State = FormParametersHelper.ToString(state)
    };

    var profile = "Transform_Resize"
        + "_w_" + Convert.ToString(Width)
        + "_h_" + Convert.ToString(Height)
        + "_m_" + Convert.ToString(Mode)
        + "_a_" + Convert.ToString(Alignment)
        + "_c_" + Convert.ToString(PadColor);

    var resizedImagePath = _imageProfileManager.GetImageProfileUrl(path, profile, filter);
    return resizedImagePath;
}
```